# Examples of Topological Spaces which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.

Tags: differential-topology

I understand that two topological spaces being homeomorphic is, in some sense, a weaker form of isomorphism than the two spaces being diffeomorphic because diffeomorphism preserves more structure.

What would be some simple examples of spaces which are homeomorphic to one another but not diffeomorphic?

Comment: I assume you want both spaces to be differentiable manifolds.

Comment: From a cursory look at the topic, elementary examples seem hard to find; some exotic examples are given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Homeomorphism_and_diffeomorphism

Comment: "Simple" depends on your level of mathematical knowledge. How is your algebraic topology?

Comment: Technically, it makes no sense to talk about topological spaces being diffeomorphic. Only spaces equipped with a smooth manifold structure can be diffeomorphic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Classification of all 28 Exotic 7-Spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/classification-of-all-28-exotic-7-spheres)

Comment: Thank you all for the responses! 
@MoisheKohan unfortunately, I don't know much Algebraic Topology at the moment but I'd appreciate it if you could drop an example or two that I can come back to when I'm further along with my studies

Comment: The you are not ready at all for the discussion of this material. Take a look at my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4116847/what-should-i-study-to-understand-milnors-exotic-7-spheres/4119375#4119375) for Milnor's construction.